# How Can I offset the center marker to right?

Tags: mapbox

I want to achieve like this http://techblog.mappy.com/Leaflet-active-area/examples/index.html

I have added a floating content in left of the section. So the marker must remain in the right side.

Here is a [demo](http://codepen.io/falz/pen/zoaoEo).

JS:

```
// ***********************************************
 mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZmFseiIsImEiOiJjaXdmczJha28wMG9sMnVsZnlxZWt1bmxhIn0.v8SlQ70Ay1MzNoPXhlXWVg';
// ***********************************************
// DID YOU FORK THIS EXAMPLE?
// Enter your access token below
// and uncomment the line to keep your
// project online!
// Need a token? Create free account 
// mapbox.com/signup
// ***********************************************
// mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN-HERE';
// ***********************************************
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: [144.985258,-37.807426],
    zoom: 14
});

var framesPerSecond = 15; 
var initialOpacity = 1
var opacity = initialOpacity;
var initialRadius = 6;
var radius = initialRadius;
var maxRadius = 18;

map.on('load', function () {

    // Add a source and layer displaying a point which will be animated in a circle.
    map.addSource('point', {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                144.985258, -37.807426
            ]
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "point",
        "source": "point",
        "type": "circle",
        "paint": {
            "circle-radius": initialRadius,
            "circle-radius-transition": {duration: 0},
            "circle-opacity-transition": {duration: 0},
            "circle-color": "#007cbf"
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "point1",
        "source": "point",
        "type": "circle",
        "paint": {
            "circle-radius": initialRadius,
            "circle-color": "#007cbf"
        }
    });


    function animateMarker(timestamp) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);

            radius += (maxRadius - radius) / framesPerSecond;
            opacity -= ( .9 / framesPerSecond );

            map.setPaintProperty('point', 'circle-radius', radius);
            map.setPaintProperty('point', 'circle-opacity', opacity);

            if (opacity <= 0) {
                radius = initialRadius;
                opacity = initialOpacity;
            } 

        }, 1000 / framesPerSecond);

    }

    // Start the animation.
    animateMarker(0);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there isn't support yet for something like fitBounds with padding. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1740

A possible workaround could be flying to the marker with an offset.

```
  map.flyTo({
    center: [144.985258, -37.807426],
    offset: [300, 0],
    speed: 0.8,
    curve: .6
  });
```